# Displaying weekly sales by day per branch mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

**Table 1 = branch**
containing

branch_id
branch_name

**Table 2 = sales_data**
containing

sales_id
sales_date
sales_branch
sales_profit

I need away of showing the total daily sales and total daily profit for each branch. I know how to bring back the result for a given week etc I am just really struggling on how to pull back the data.

I also need all the branches to be shown at all time and if they haven't sold anything to display a 0.

I have put together a quick image (http://i37.photobucket.com/albums/e71/dannyflap/screen_shot.jpg) of how I would like the finished. This is really driving me nuts :(

UPDATE

```
select sales_branch, WEEKDAY(sales_date), COUNT(sales_profit), SUM(sales_profit)
FROM sales_date
GROUP BY sales_branch, WEEKDAY(sales_date)
```

This then brings back the following example. Figures are made up.

```
sales_branch, day, units, profit:

| branch1 | 0 (as day) | 16 | 439 |

| branch1 | 1 (as day) | 12 | 651 |

| branch1 | 2 (as day) | 22 | 312 |

| branch1 | 3 (as day) | 61 | 614 |

| branch1 | 4 (as day) | 12 | 541 |

| branch1 | 5 (as day) | 24 | 102 |

| branch1 | 6 (as day) | 21 | 145 |
```

Comment: What do you have so far? What have you tried? Where is it going wrong?

Comment: I have added what I have so far

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a foreign key in sales_data that maps to branch.

assuming sales_branch is something different than branch_name or branch_id, sales_data should contain:

```
sales_id sales_date sales_branch branch_id sales_profit
```

Also - you should post your code for getting back the result for a given week and we can help you build on that rather than give you the entire answer.

**EDIT**
Ok with modifying your sales_data table to have a foreign key branch_id to the branch table, this query should get you closer to what you're looking for.

```
SELECT b.branch_name, WEEKDAY(s.sales_date), COUNT(s.sales_profit), SUM(s.sales_profit)
FROM branch b
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales_data on s.branch_id = b.branch_id
GROUP BY b.branch_id, WEEKDAY(s.sales_date)
```

Comment: branch_name is used to populate the the drop down box when reporting a sale which is the added to the sales_data as sales_branch if that makes sense.

Comment: select sales_branch, WEEKDAY(sales_date), COUNT(sales_profit), SUM(sales_profit)
FROM sales_date
GROUP BY sales_branch, WEEKDAY(sales_date)

This then brings back the following example. Figures are made up.
sales_branch, day, units, profit:
| branch1 | 0 (as day) | 16 | 439 |
| branch1 | 1 (as day) | 12 | 651 |
| branch1 | 2 (as day) | 22 | 312 |
| branch1 | 3 (as day) | 61 | 614 |
| branch1 | 4 (as day) | 12 | 541 |
| branch1 | 5 (as day) | 24 | 102 |
| branch1 | 6 (as day) | 21 | 145 |

Comment: You should not store the branch name twice. You should store the branch_id in the sales_data table as a foreign key to branch_id in the branch table.

Comment: Please post it as an update to your question so everyone can see it easily.

Comment: I will try it in the morning and let you know. Thanks for the help to far :)

Comment: It's not going to get you to the image you attached, but it helps get your data a little better. You'll probably have to take the data from your query and parse it a bit to get it in the format you want.

Comment: sorry for sounding dump but why have you put b.branch_name instead of just branch_name? same for the table branch b instead of just branch? :)

Comment: I thought you'd ask. If you look at my from statement, i used `FROM branch b`. Basically i'm just using b to reference that table. I could have just as easily done this:`SELECT branch.branch_name FROM branch`, but using `b` is shorter.

Comment: sorry you have totally lost me now :( i think i need to go to bed my head is going to pop haha :)

Comment: After a good nights sleep I am now functioning and thanks for the link it really helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would have to do an outer join on table 1's `branch_id` and table 2's `sales_branch` and loop through the result to produce the table. With an outer join those branches who haven't sold anything will get a `NULL`, I think.

Is it the table generating you're having problem with? I don't think it's wise to do some spectacular SQL for this problem. My two cents.

Comment: yes this aswell im having trouble pulling back they results going across